# SQL performance questions

Tags: sql

I'm rewokring a huge SQL query (2k lines), containing lots of `CASE` where each `CASE` is another query. I'd like to know what to do and what to avoid, in terms of performance.

Should I make a bigger general query, that `JOIN`s everything I'll need, and then, condition each `CASE` with the things I joined.

Or do I write a new query for each `CASE`? (with most subqueries from CASEs using the same tables).

I've also seen subqueries with an AS at the end, to use the resulting datas in the select or in conditions.

And `WITH`, before the `SELECT`, for mostly the same effect, creating a kind of table for conditions and display.

Which one is better to use in terms of performance?

Thanks

Comment: That will be **very much** depending on which **concrete RDBMS** you're using (SQL is just the query language - that doesn't tell us, which DB systems you're actually running this huge query on), and it will also depend very heavily on the table and indexing structures in place, and the amount and "type" of data in your tables.... this question is waaaaaaaaaaaaaay too broad to answer .....

Comment: Please split your problem in smaller parts and try to ask questions for every part where you see performance issues.

Comment: Please post the query.  Having 2000 lines and lots of `CASE` statements is not necessarily bad, but having nested queries within those CASE statements could be.  It's possibly you can replace some of those nested queries with a simple JOIN, but you'd need to post the query first so we can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, look if some CASE or subselect is repeated several times, do a WITH containing that part of the query and then replace it in the code so you only do the select one time in the with.

Second of all, try to avoid subselects as much as you can, again using WITH is a good way to do that.

Try to clarify each CASE so it's easy to read in vertical to avoid making mistakes when modifying it if necessary.

Remind that if the WITH is too big is possible that you consume all the memory so the query won't work, so add there the most repetitive sentences, but not all of them.

If possible, try to make the big query a lot of little querys splitted and add them all into a package so it's easier to keep track of the error and a good control of the process.

edit:

**All this guessing you're using Oracle!!**